# Efficiently calculate the statistics on a given metrics on a list of students

Tags: java, algorithm, oop

Student.java

```
public class Student{
    /*
    Metrics examples (out of 100):
    mathScore:98
    scienceScore:99
    englishScore:92
    */
    private Map<String, Double> metrics = new HashMap<>();

}
```

Statistics

```
public enum Statistic {

     AVERAGE,
     MIN,
     MAX
}
```

Result

```
public class Result {
  private Statistic statistic;
  private double value;
  private String metric;
}
```

What's the most efficient way to build an engine that can perform requested statical analysis based on the requested metrics on a list of students

Here's an example:

Say I have a list of Students.

```
List<Student> students = [john, json, elliot, sarah, callie, matt, leigh]; //Assume each entry is an object
```

I also have list of metrics  I'm interested in

```
List<String> metrics  =["mathScore", "scienceScore"]; //Just an example. I can add additional metrics to this list or remove them.
```

And the statistics I want to perform

```
List<Statistic> stats = [MIN, MAX]; //Just an example. I can request additional operations if necessary.
```

Here's the signature of the method that needs to be efficiently built

```
public List<Resut> calculate( List<String> requestedMetrics, List<Statistic> requestedStatistics, List<Student> students){

}
```

Here are my initial thoughts

1. Convert requestedMetrics and requestedStatistics to sets to
   eliminate duplicates.
2. Iterate through each metric. For each metric,
   iterate through each statistic and calculate it. Is there a better
   way? And how does one go about breaking down the implementation in
   to smaller functions etc. for a cleaner solution?
3. What about creating a cache (map) so that we don't need to reprocess 
   everything again and again?

Here's my current implementation

```
@Component
public class StatisticalAnalysis {

    @Override
    public List<Result> calculate(List<Student> students, List<String> metrics, List<Statistic> stats) {

        return analyze(new HashSet<>(students), new HashSet<>(metrics), new HashSet<>(stats));
    }

    public List<Result> analyze(HashSet<Student> students, HashSet<String> metrics, HashSet<Statistic> stats) {

        List<Result> calculate = new ArrayList<>(metrics.size());

        for (String metric : metrics) {
            for (Statistic stat : stats) {
               results.add(createResult(students, metric, stat ));
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    private Result createResult(HashSet<Student> students, String metric, Statistic stat) {

       return new Result(metric, stat, calcStatValue(students, metric, stat));

    }

    private double calcStatValue(HashSet<Student> students, String metric, Statistic stat) {


        List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>(students.size());

        for(Student measurement: students){
            Double value = measurement.getMetric(metric);
            if(value!=null)
                values.add(value);
        }

        return performStatOperation(stat, values);

    }

    private double performStatOperation(Statistic stat, List<Double> values) {
        switch (stat) {
            case MIN:
                return Collections.min(values);
            case MAX:
                return Collections.max(values);
            case AVERAGE:
                return values.stream().mapToDouble(val -> val).average().orElse(0.0);
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Calculation of Statistic %s is currently unsupported", stat));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is more of a please do my homework, rather than a specific question. I suggest you attempt the problem then edit your question to ask how your completed method can be optimized or split into smaller parts.

Comment: Yes, please attempt some code, we are not a coding service.  Also "is this the best way" questions are probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), one of SO's sister sites.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Added the implementation. Thank you!

Comment: @markspace I agree. I've added my impl and created a new question in the Code review space. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225099/efficiently-calculate-the-statistics-on-a-given-metrics-on-a-list-of-students

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to implementing your own solution, you could use the statistics libraries from Apache Commons Math, for instance. These offer descriptive and summary statistics as well as regression and statistical tests. That seems to cover what you need.

Official docs link for [Apache Commons Math Statistics](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.2_Descriptive_statistics)

Answer (score 0):

The metrics could be an enum instead of a string so that they are defined in one spot and can be used easily in all of the code.

Also, if the students are not modified after construction, their class can already contain a List ready to be used instead of depending on an external method. The only calculation being made is sorting the grades to find the min and the max, which is a trivial construction overhead given the short list of metrics.

Otherwise, you can cache a student’s result list and mark it for cache invalidation if its metrics are modified.